# skim(iris) giving an error message using Google Colab

Tags: r, google-colaboratory, skimr

Running 4.3.2 on Google Colab.

When I do skim(iris) or any data set for that matter I get the usual output and then an error on the bottom:

```
── Variable type: numeric ──────────────────────────────────────────────────────
  skim_variable n_missing complete_rate mean    sd  p0 p25  p50 p75 p100 hist 
1 Sepal.Length          0             1 5.84 0.828 4.3 5.1 5.8  6.4  7.9 ▆▇▇▅▂
2 Sepal.Width           0             1 3.06 0.436 2   2.8 3    3.3  4.4 ▁▆▇▂▁
3 Petal.Length          0             1 3.76 1.77  1   1.6 4.35 5.1  6.9 ▇▁▆▇▂
4 Petal.Width           0             1 1.20 0.762 0.1 0.3 1.3  1.8  2.5 ▇▁▇▅▃
Error in is.null(text_repr) || nchar(text_repr) == 0L: 'length = 15' in coercion to 'logical(1)'
Traceback:
```

Anyone know what is going on? Thanks!

Comment: Can you run this locally, so you can check whether it's actually related to Colab?

Comment: Yup works local and on rstudio.cloud. Just gives an error message in colab (rstudio.cloud also running 4.3.2, local running 4.2.2)

Comment: Weird, is it an old version of skimr? Can you update it?